How to restore to the latest backup I have in Azure App Service?
The backup is performed automatically every hour. I need to use the Azure SDK to perform a restore, and that restore should be based on the latest backup.
var backups = webSiteForRestore.GetSiteBackups();
var latestBackup = backups.OrderByDescending(b => b.Data.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault();
latestBackup is null for me, and I don't know why.
When I enter through the Azure portal and go to the App Service, then to backups, I have at least 10 backups because it runs every hour.

Are you getting any error ?

First of all, verify if backup configuration is correct or not
Under settings tab, select Backups. Confirm that backups are scheduled to run every hour and that previous backups are listed as successful. If all correctly configured, you should see a schedule like "Every 1 hour" and a list of recent backups with status Succeeded.

If backups are not configured, use the portal to set them up with your storage account and container.
Ensure you have access to the backups programmatically.
How?
Run this command to create the SAS token
az storage container generate-sas --account-name arkoappbackups --name webapp-backups \
    --permissions rw --expiry $(date -u -d "1 year" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ') --output tsv


Construct the full SAS URL by appending the token to the container URL
https://arkoappbackups.blob.core.windows.net/<your-container>?<SAS_TOKEN>

From the code side, install and configure the Azure SDK for .NET
dotnet add package Azure.Identity
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Websites

Example

Similarly install other packages
and update your program.cs accordingly, replace with your own subscription, client and tenant ids
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.Models;

public class BackupRestoreExample
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var clientId = "77585126-123-456-abc-defghijk";
        var clientSecret = "0lq8Q~x12345678abc~8iOJ_OS7aUN";
        var tenantId = "9329c02a-1234-5678-abcd-b6e37b19af6d";
        var subscriptionId = "12345-678-9abc-82d5-9d23dbddfc7d";

        
        var resourceGroup = "arkorg";
        var webAppName = "LogStreamApp";

        
        var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
            .FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

        // Authenticate and create the Azure client
        var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

        // Fetch the Web App
        var webApp = azure.WebApps.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, webAppName);
        if (webApp == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Web app not found.");
            return;
        }

        // Retrieve Backups
        var backups = await azure.WebApps.Manager.Inner.WebApps
            .ListBackupsAsync(resourceGroup, webAppName);

        // Get the Latest Backup
        var latestBackup = backups
            .OrderByDescending(b => b.Scheduled)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (latestBackup != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Restoring backup from {latestBackup.Scheduled}");

            // Perform the Restore operation using the latest backup
            var restoreRequest = new RestoreRequestInner
            {
                StorageAccountUrl = latestBackup.StorageAccountUrl,
                BlobName = latestBackup.BlobName,
                Overwrite = true
            };

            await azure.WebApps.Manager.Inner.WebApps
                .RestoreAsync(resourceGroup, webAppName, webAppName, restoreRequest);

            Console.WriteLine("Restore operation started successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No backups found.");
        }
    }
}


You can verify the same from portal

Reference- Back up and restore your app in Azure App Service

This is for a custom backup, but is it possible to use an automatic backup?

This code will automatically select the latest backup (whether automatic or custom) based on the scheduled timestamp. It retrieves all backups, sorts them by date, and then chooses the most recent one. The ListBackupsAsync method does not distinguish between automatic and custom backups. It lists all backups, and the code will select the latest one regardless of type.
